# Opening multiple web page in order using webbrowser.open

Tags: python, windows, python-webbrowser

So what i want to do is very simple. I have a list of words and for each word in the list i want to open three websites. Like website 1: word 1,website 2: word 1,website 3: word 1,website 1: word 2, ... . My attempt to do so was as fallow:

```
import webbrowser

wordList = ["word1", "word2", "word3",]

for word in wordList:
    url = "https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/" + word
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=False)
    url = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/" + word
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=False)
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + word
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=False)
```

The problem is when the list is long then the websites do not open in order. Is there a way to make sure they open in correct order?

I use Firefox as default browser and my OS is windows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the URLs are being opened too fast. If the main focus is that they should be in order, then I would suggest the following code:

```
import webbrowser
import time

LOAD_TIME = 0.2 # s

word_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3",]
url_list = ["https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/", "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/", "https://www.google.com/search?q="]

for word, url in zip(word_list, url_list):
    status = webbrowser.open(url+word, new=2, autoraise=False)
    time.sleep(LOAD_TIME)
```

It just gives the script some time before moving on to the next `open()` exicution.

The looping through the combined variables is set up with a cleaner `zip`, and you can test the variable `LOAD_TIME` a few times. You might need a longer or shorter load time interval depending on your machine, internet speed, etc. If speed is not a concern but the order of the tabs is most important, you can set this variable to be quite high.

EDIT: If you want to avoid the `time` module, the following also worked for me:

```
import webbrowser

word_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3",]
url_list = ["https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/", "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/", "https://www.google.com/search?q="]

for word, url in zip(word_list, url_list):
    if webbrowser.open(url+word, new=2, autoraise=False):
        continue
```

Explanation: The code waits for a response of `True` or `False` from the current `webbrowser.open()` call before moving on to the next.

EDIT2:
If you want to open each word in all three links, then the `zip` function is not the one. You might want a double-for loop instead. If you want the order in which the links are opened to be `(url1+word1), (url2+word1), (url3+word1), (url1+word2), ...`, then the double for loop would look like:

```
import webbrowser

word_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3",]
url_list = ["https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/", "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/", "https://www.google.com/search?q="]

for word in word_list:
    for url in url_list:
        if webbrowser.open(url+word, new=2, autoraise=False):
            continue
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping for another solution, something more reliable. Cause as you said this way there might be some dependencies on internet speed and so on. something like maybe the application could wait for browser response or i don't know something that could fix the problem for good.

Comment: I'm not so sure how it behaves with various machines or internet speeds. However, I quickly tested it with a 10 times larger url_list and a `LOAD_TIME=0.0001`, and they all opened in the correct order. Can you confirm if it does the same for you as well?

Comment: So just to make sure i do the test with ten times larger url_list or ten times larger word_list ? cause my concern is when the word_list is large.

Comment: @mike I just edited with a new suggestion. It waits for a response from the `open` call before moving on to the next. I tested it with 30 browser calls and opened in the correct order. Let me know if you experience different results!

Comment: @mike the way I checked if it works for larger lists was just to expand the lists to be ten times their original size `word_list=word_list*10` and `url_list=url_list*10`.  I then checked to make sure the browser tabs were in the correct order.

Comment: the output of second solution is kinda not right. for me it just pops up three first words each in one of three websites.

Comment: I'm not sure what your error is. What links are being opened? Why is the way it is working incorrect? How would you like for them to be opened? Would you like it like (url1+word1), (url1+word2), (url1+word3), (url2+word1), ... etc?

Comment: The output i am looking for is (url1,word1) (url2,word1) (url3,word1) (url1,word2) (url2,word2) (url2,word2) and so on. when i test second solution i get (url1,word1),(url2,word2),(url3,word3) and just 3 tabs for 3 first words opens.

Comment: Edited one last time to fit the order you wanted, `(url1,word1) (url2,word1) (url3,word1) (url1,word2) (url2,word2), ...`. Please see the most recent edit of my answer and then mark the thread as solved if it works on your machine. :)

Comment: Didn't work for me, But thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you explain what is going wrong? If I copy-paste the last code-block it opens them in the right order for me

Comment: still it does not have any specific order, kinda looks random.sometimes works but not all the time.